# Pass sequentially named variables to functions within a loop in R

Tags: r

I have created some sequentially named variable i.e `holder1, holder2, holder3,` which contain single strings I would like to pass to `grep`

However I am having trouble getting the holder variables to return their values rather than just their names when I pass it to grep, my current attempt looks like:

```
vec<-c("str1","str2","str3","str4")

for(i in 1:length(vec)){
  assign(paste("holder",i,sep=""),vec[i])
   positions[i]<-grep( eval (paste ("holder",i,sep="")) ,colnames(df),ignore.case=TRUE)

}
```

This will search for `holder1` within the colnames of `df`, which is not what I want, I would like to search for the contents of `holder i` within the df i.e `str1` `str2` e.t.c.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Roland thanks for your concern, but I'm not terribly concerned about performance in this context so am happy to use a for loop as it is what I am familiar with.

Comment: it is not only question of performance, mostly question of writting some clear code understandable by everyone. It seems indeed much easier to read `log(exp(a)*exp(b))` than `a+b` ...

Comment: You use a scew driver to hammer a nail. Although it's not terribly effcient, it can be done. However, a hammer is a much better and safer tool for the task.

Comment: @Roland please tell me how I could have written this in better practice, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: You don't explain very well, what you ultimately would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with eval and parse:

```
  for(i in 1:length(vec)){
    assign(paste("holder",i,sep=""),vec[i])
    print ( paste ("holder",i,sep="") )
    positions<-c(positions,grep( eval( parse(text= paste ("holder",i,sep="")) ),colnames(data),ignore.case=TRUE))
  }
```